# Ubuntu 16.04 How to Disable UFW On Startup Through Config

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, ufw

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 AWS instance that I accidentally locked myself out of by enabling UFW without allowing port 22 for SSH. I've created a new instance and mounted the volume of the affected instance to it.

Now I have access to the file system of the affected instance, how do I stop UFW from running on startup so that I can access the instance again through SSH? Alternatively, how do I allow access to port 22 for SSH through config files?

I've looked around online and my file structure doesn't seem to match what other people are using. In `/media/myDrive/lib/ufw` I don't have `user.rules` or `user6.rules`; these are in `/etc/ufw/`. I've edited the `user*.rules` files as below to allow access, but when I rebooted the server, I still couldn't access it via SSH.

```
#user.rules
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
#user6.rules
-A ufw6-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw6-user-input -p udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Referenced from this SO question: [Can't ssh into AWS EC2 after enabling firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370732/cant-ssh-into-aws-ec2-after-enabling-firewall)

Comment: Hi, Donglecow, I've added a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927375/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-disable-ufw-on-startup-through-config/932838#comment1934457_1022361), under the @jdgregson's answer. I just read your rules and I think you need to use `-I`nsert to the beginning of the chain instead of `-A`ppend to the end. Also, probably (sorry currently I do not have UFW installed), the default `INPUT` chain will be read before the UFW's one, so you can try with some rules as: `-I INPUT ...` ...and the last one you don't need to allow UDP on the SSH port.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to disable UFW on startup through change of `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` in this way:

```
ENABLED=no
```

Comment: It's not working :/ I have this enabled=0 but still i'm unable to ssh...

Answer (score 6):

pa4080's answer *seems* like the correct answer, but I found that UFW was blocking pings and Samba connections after a default Ubuntu 14.04 install, even though `ENABLED=no` is the default setting in `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf`. After I stopped UFW with `service ufw stop` I was able to connect to the machine as expected.

**Disabling UFW on startup**

On Ubuntu 14.10 and earlier: `sudo echo manual > /etc/init/ufw.override`

On Ubuntu 15.04 and later: `sudo systemctl disable ufw`

On anything else or just to be sure: `sudo echo "service ufw stop" >> /etc/init.d/rc.local`

Comment: Thanks for this. I've long worked around the problem now. @pa4080's answer didn't work for me which is why I didn't accept it. Though this looks like it would've been a more promising line to investigate.

Comment: Yes, you are right, jdgregson, recently I found that even you remove UFW, it leaves some rules in `iptables` that should be removed by hand.

Comment: @pa4080 So much for being an "Uncomplicated" Firewall...